# NSStackView Subviews not Resizing Sub-stack views

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, cocoa

I have 2 horizontal NSStackViews within 1 vertical NSStackView within a NSView. It seems I cannot resize the whole view even with the constraints. If I increase the width by dragging the IB view handle the views will grow. But is seems if I try to shrink them by pulling the IB view handles towards each other the stack views stop shrinking the parent view width is 800 pix. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: OK, I tried adding just a single NSStackView with no subviews, that hugs the walls of the parent view. Now the stack view behaves as I want it, resizing with the parent view.

Answer (score 1):

If you want child view inside vertical `NSStackView` to fill its parent width, then reduce `contentCompressionResistancePriority`

```
myChildView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
myChildView.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(
  NSLayoutConstraint.Priority(rawValue: 1),
  for: .horizontal
)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
  myChildView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
])

NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({context in
  context.duration = 0.25
  context.allowsImplicitAnimation = true
  stackView.insertArrangedSubview(myChildView, at: 1)

  view.layoutSubtreeIfNeeded()
}, completionHandler: nil)
```

Comment: Content compression resistance has nothing to do with view expansion. Like it says, it resist compression below its intrinsic content size, not expansion.

Answer (score 0):

After adding a single single horizontal NSStackView (previous comment), I then added two vertical NSStackViews then set the content compression resistance priority to the lowest setting (250).